# Автоматическое определение пользовательского выбора

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Всем доброго времени суток, в ходе познания дзен программирования на C#
Прошу прощения WPF
Возник такого рода вопрос:
Имеем массив с данными GetFiles в который помещаются данные с поиска файлов по папкам.

```
public string[] GetFiles = Directory.GetFiles(MainWindow.FExplorerDir, "NDP*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Далее происходит вывод содержимого данного массива в ListBox

```
InstallLB.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < GetFiles.Length; i++)
        {
            InstallLB.Items.Add(GetFiles[i]);

        }
```

Есть обработчик нажатий 
Так вот в данный момент я явно присваиваю обработчику данные, а хотелось бы что бы программа сама определила какой пункт из списка пользователь выбрал и далее происходило бы само действие.

```
private void InstallLBSelectCh(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        switch (InstallLB.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                p.StartInfo.FileName = GetFiles[0];
                p.Start();
                break;
            case 1:
                p.StartInfo.FileName = GetFiles[1];
                p.Start();
                break;
            case 2:
                p.StartInfo.FileName = GetFiles[2];
                p.Start();
                break;
            default: goto case 0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: winforms или wpf?

Comment: `p.StartInfo.FileName = GetFiles[  InstallLB.SelectedIndex  ];`?

Comment: @tym32167 Спасибо за подсказку, все работает.

Comment: @mindevis пожалуйста